# Polymorphic method return type down-casting in java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, downcast

So I don't know if this is possible I've tried searching it but maybe my search terms are off. Basically I'm wondering, is there a way to create a generic function/method in a super class that returns the downcast object.

```
class A {
    public <downcasted type (in this example B if called from a B instance)> test() {
        return this;
    }
}

class B extends A { }

B b = new B().test()
```

basically having "test()" return the B instance as type B even know the function/method is declared purely in the parent class?

I know I can cast the variable, tho having many functions some of which may return Lists of the class type, etc become troublesome. I also realize I could @override the function in B and do a "return (B)this.super()" thing, but again wrapping many functions is tedious and makes makes updating the base classes code more painful.

I also know you can do

```
"class A<T extends A>"
```

and then define B as

```
"class B extends A<B>"
```

but then if you want to make a "C" that extends "B" it breaks.

So is this type of behavior possible? If so, what is it called and how do I implement it?

An example as to where this behavior could be useful would be any base data structures you want to make extendable like an N-Ary Tree that you extend into oct/quad tree structure and/or an extended class that adds a "Name" and "Attributes" or something for a xml-like node.

Edit:
This seems to work(as far as the linter is concerned), it's a bit more work to implement the base methods but it's got the desired end result as far as I can tell. That said when I attempt to run it, it gives me a "cannot find symbol: class type" error. :S

```
static class D extends auto {

    final Class type = getClass();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends type> T test() {
        return (T)type.cast(this);
    }
}

static class E extends D { }
static class F extends E { }

static {
    D d = new D().test();
    E e = new E().test();
    F f = new F().test();
}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand, what is your end goal.

Comment: @NareshJoshi End goal is to create code that can be inherited by many different subclasses while providing methods that are seemingly first class to the inheriting class. The question gives some of these examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

There is a simpler way, which seems to work:

```
class Alpha {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    <T extends Alpha> T test() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

```
class B extends A { }
```

However, that does not support method chaining.

---

#### Original post

You need `test()` to return a subtype of `A`, rather than `A` itself. In order to do this, the signature of the `A` class could be this:

```
class A<T extends A<?>> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T test() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

If you create a class `B` extending `A`, you will need `B.test()` to return an instance of `B`, without needing to override `test()` returning a specific type. You could then do something like this:

```
class B<T extends B<?>> extends A<T> { }
```

Now `T` is a subclass of `B`, and because `test()`'s return type is `T`, it will return a `B` instance. Further subclassing can be done in the same way:

```
class C<T extends C<?>> extends B<T> { }
```

And statements like this will work:

```
C<?> c = new C<>().test();
```

Comment: That works so I cant fault the answer, I was hoping there was a way to make it a little more transparent for an end user using the class, like if it was  in a library for instance. Having to call B<?> b = new B<>().test(), would be nice if there was a way to just do B b = new B().test(), but I guess there isn't?

Comment: good find in your "update" I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed about the method chaining, thats unfortunate :( I find it strange that languages boast generics yet they don't implement a method for doing what I described in a "non-hacky" manner {not using @SurpressWarnings() / lose of chaining / non specified return type in the auto complete "B b = new A().test() passes lint check."})

Comment: Yeah, that's probably because there is currently no syntax to return the class's type from a method. For example, a syntax like `this test() { return this; }` or something would return an `A` instance when it is called from an `A` instance, `B` when it is called from a `B` instance, et cetera. Maybe in the future it would be possible, but, unfortunately, currently not.